# Multiple Aggregations in same dataset in apache kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka stream with following columns:

**pageid**: string

**userid**: string

**pageviewtime**: long

**usergender**: string

I wish to have 2 aggregations against this stream for top 20 pages based on viewtime

1. Number of distinct user ids who viewed the page
2. Total viewtime for the page

So the result stream will have 3 columns:

1. pageid
2. sum(pageviewtime)
3. number_of_distinct_users

We can easily do this in KSQL, but want to understand how will we do 2 aggregations in "Kafka Streams"

Comment: Have you tried creating two separate kafka streams topologies?

Comment: Then I would have to join those two resulting streams to create the desired result, right?

Comment: Join the user counts and session times by page ID sounds correct to me. Is there a specific reason you're not able to use KSQL, though?